# When can a (spell) skill be levelled?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

In the following screenshot I've just gained level 5, and have a skill point to spend:

[image: character sheet]

I want to max *Geomancer* and *Pyrokinetic*. Somehow (I do *not* know how) I achievend 2 points in Geomancer. However, I can *not* skill up Pyrokenitics. Why?

I've checked around the UI, but there are no tooltips explaining this at all. I've noticed blue stats on my character sheet, but found that these are increases gained from items, which is not the case for Geomancer. I don't understand why Geomancer skill can be 2, but I cannot put my available skill point in Pyrokinetic.

**What are the prerequisites for levelling up a (spell) skill?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question with a simple answer.

In the screenshot you got 1 point in pyrokinetic so if you want to increase it to 2 you need 2 available points, to increase it to 3 you would need 3 points.

A little list:

- lvl 1 = 1 point overall
- lvl 2 = 3 points overall (1 for lvl 1 and 2 for lvl 2)
- lvl 3 = 6 points overall (1 for lvl 1, 2 for lvl 2 and 3 for lvl 3)

and so on. Note that you only get 1 ability point to spend at level 2 - 5, but after that it's more per level. See [this wiki page at Divinity's Wikia](http://divinity.wikia.com/wiki/Divinity:_Original_Sin_Character_Progression) for more detailed information.

That's how it works for all Skills/Abilitys in Divinity.

Comment: Aha. And do you get more points to spend from a level up later on?

Comment: you mean after the first 10 lvl you get 2 points each lvl for example? if yes you get 1 point lvl 1-5; 2points lvl 6-10; 3points for lvl 11++ all about that what you wanna know can be found here (care the link contains spoilers) http://divinity.wikia.com/wiki/Divinity:_Original_Sin_Character_Progression